# Organizational Chart in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts, google-apps, analytics

I am trying to make an org chart in VF page using google analytics, it working all well but facing a logical issue. There are some 50 child accounts to the parent and in org chart all the child accounts are displayed in a single line hence there isn't enough screen space to show all the accounts. Is there any way in which i can break the accounts which are in the same level to the next line like we use 
 in html.

Got all the details of the chart from 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it would be easier to display the tree vertically instead of customizing it in its current orientation, but of course let us know if that is an issue.  Here's some other users experiences with this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790205/is-there-anyway-to-vertically-align-the-boxes-in-google-org-chart-visualization